# Collectionview different background colors on cells

Tags: ios, background, uicollectionview, cell

From what I see from the image below, correct me if I am wrong, this is a collectionView. My question is, how do I set the background colors to the cells to make them look like this?

I thought that it might be something with an RNG (random number generator) that only generates numbers between 1.0 to 1.99. Then I multiply the brightest color with the RNG number per cell. What am I missing or doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Show us exactly what you tried and tell us exactly what is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're over-engineering it. There's only three different colors in that collection view.

Hex Values:

- 544A3F
- 433C35
- 4F473C

Comment: That might be true. I will use the simple hex values. Unnecessarily to make it more difficult than it needs to be.

Comment: Agreed. This site could help you get shades for different case colors: http://highintegritydesign.com/tools/tinter-shader/